# accessing request object in a SessionWizardView in django

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls, django-formwizard

I am using a django forms `SessionWizardView` to implement a form wizard. The url configuration is as follows;

```
url(r'^contact/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.ContactWizard.as_view([DummyForm, OtherForm]), name='contact'),
```

The idea here is that I am passing a primary key so that I can populate the form with some initial data. The form is loaded from another view as follows:

```
def populate_review_form(request):
    pk = 2
    return redirect('contact', pk=pk)
```

Here I am trying to pass a hard-coded primary key to the form.

Now, my form implementation is simple where I am overriding the `get_form_initial` to generate the initial value for the form as follows:

```
class ContactWizard(SessionWizardView):
    def get_template_names(self):
        return "test.html"

    def get_form_initial(self, step):
        pk = self.request.GET.get('pk')
        # Just attempt to print the primary key
        print pk, self.request.GET
        return {}    

    def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):
        return HttpResponseRedirect('index')
```

The issue is that this always prints `None <QueryDict: {}>`. So, basically my parameter is not being passed or I am unable to access the correct `request` object. Is it possible in Django to have this communication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pk` is stored in `self.kwargs`:

```
pk = self.kwargs['pk']
```

Comment: Thank you! That works. Still getting my head around this!